# Fread returns wrong value when reading unsigned int with large values

Tags: c, fread, unsigned-integer

When I read an unsigned int from a binary file, it only reads the correct value if the value in the file is fairly low - when I try to read a value over 150,000 it gives me something like 9000... It's weird. Smaller numbers work perfectly however, like 50,000...

```
unsigned int value;

file = fopen(filePath, "rb");
fseek(file, 0, 0);
fread(&value, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, file);

printf("Value from file: %i\n", value);
```

The binary file was created on the same computer & operating system that the program runs on... what am I missing? The binary files are created properly and most of them do return the correct value & work fine, only the ones with large numbers don't...

Comment: Why not use `fscanf()` if you want formatted IO?

Comment: How *was* the binary file created?

Comment: post a hex dump of the file. Also check the return value of `fread`

Comment: hi, writing to binary: fwrite(&value, sizeof(unsigned int), 1, file);

Comment: `printf("Value from file: %i\n", value);` should generate a compiler warning.  Save time by enabling all warnings.

Comment: Tip: rather than "when I try to read a value over 150,000 it gives me something like 9000...", post the specific value that was read and the copy/paste of the value that was printed.

Answer (score 2):

You got the right value but used the wrong format string to print it, yielding undefined behavior. `%i` is for signed integers. You need `%u`.

The above is definitely a bug, but if it's not the source of the problem at hand, it's also possible that you're using a legacy compiler on Windows and the writing code is failing to open the file in binary mode. In that case, the value may get corrupted if one of the bytes happens to be `0x0a`, in which case the value read back would be wrong.

Comment: Although a mis-match specifier is used, that does not well explain "when I try to read a value over 150,000 it gives me something like 9000... It's weird. Smaller numbers work perfectly however, like 50,000...".  Yet I think this answer is correct and OP's problem description is amiss.

Comment: Yeah, I read those specific numbers after writing the answer and they didn't make sense, but I figured the question is sufficiently poorly stated that they might be fake values OP is mis-remembering. I added another possible explanation to the answer, too.